# text field value should not be dulpicated using play framework in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

i'm new to scala i have created the textbox and the textbox should not allow duplicate entries like tom (tom name already exists) can anyone provide the answer

here my db query

```
def create(contact: Contact) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("INSERT INTO contacts(name, emailAddress ,phone , age) VALUES({name},{emailAddress},{phone},{age})").on(

        "name" -> contact.name,
        "emailAddress" -> contact.emailAddress,
        "phone"->contact.phone,
        "age"->contact.age
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
```

and my views

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Contacts.create) {

    @helper.inputText(form("name"), '_label -> "Name",'class -> "textstyle", 'placeholder -> "Name")
```

Comment: What have you already to check whether it exists (nothing about that in the code)

Comment: yeah i don't know how to do that can anyone suggest

Comment: we can able to do like this in java
Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = 
    con.prepareStatement
    ("SELECT questid FROM completedQuests WHERE characterid = ? AND questid = ?");
ps.setInt (1, characterId);
ps.setInt (2, questId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
    // Quest already completed
} else {
    // Quest not completed yet
}

how to do with in scala?

Comment: Have you tried at first to code the same query using Anorm? I don't see so in the question/code

Comment: i'm afraid i'm really new to scala , i ain't know it

Comment: Can u please tell me how to findbyusername works in scala

Comment: val checkname= Constraint[String] { (name: String) =>
    Contact.findByName(name)
      .map(e => Invalid("The user " + e.name + "already exists"))
      .getOrElse(Valid)
  }

Comment: here Constraint and findbyname shows error

Comment: There is no "magic" findByUser, it must be implemented using the mentioned query. If you are looking for an ORM, that's another topic

Comment: ok can u suggest any site for deep dive into scala using play framework

Comment: and rightnow my question is textbox need to check before the name is exist on to the db or not how could i do tat

Comment: It's recommanded to first have a look, in particular how MVC is managed by the framework